# Enumerate all users in LDAP with PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'd like to create a php script that runs as a daily cron. What I'd like to do is enumerate through all users within an Active Directory, extract certain fields from each entry, and use this information to update fields within a MySQL database.

Basically what I want to to do is sync up certain user information between Active Directory and a MySQL table.

The problem I have is that the sizelimit on the Active Directory server is often set at 1000 entries per search result. I had hoped that the php function "ldap_next_entry" would get around this by only fetching one entry at a time, but before you can call "ldap_next_entry", you first have to call "ldap_search", which can trigger the SizeLimit exceeded error.

Is there any way besides removing the sizelimit from the server? Can I somehow get "pages" of results?

BTW - I am currently not using any 3rd party libraries or code. Just PHPs ldap methods. Although, I am certainly open to using a library if that will help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've been struck by the same problem while developing Zend_Ldap for the Zend Framework. I'll try to explain what the real problem is, but to make it short: **until PHP 5.4, it wasn't possible to use paged results from an Active Directory with an unpatched PHP (`ext/ldap`) version due to limitations in exactly this extension**.

Let's try to unravel the whole thing... Microsoft Active Directory uses a so called server control to accomplish server-side result paging. This control ist described in [RFC 2696 "LDAP Control Extension for Simple Paged Results Manipulation"](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2696.txt) .

`ext/php` offers an access to LDAP control extensions via its [`ldap_set_option()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-set-option.php) and the `LDAP_OPT_SERVER_CONTROLS` and `LDAP_OPT_CLIENT_CONTROLS` option respectively. To set the paged control you do need the control-oid, which is `1.2.840.113556.1.4.319`, and we need to know how to encode the control-value (this is described in the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2696.txt)). The value is an octet string wrapping the BER-encoded version of the following SEQUENCE (copied from the RFC):

```
realSearchControlValue ::= SEQUENCE {
        size            INTEGER (0..maxInt),
                                -- requested page size from client
                                -- result set size estimate from server
        cookie          OCTET STRING
}
```

So we can set the appropriate server control prior to executing the LDAP query:

```
$pageSize    = 100;
$pageControl = array(
    'oid'        => '1.2.840.113556.1.4.319', // the control-oid
    'iscritical' => true, // the operation should fail if the server is not able to support this control
    'value'      => sprintf ("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", 48, 5, 2, 1, $pageSize, 4, 0) // the required BER-encoded control-value
);
```

This allows us to send a paged query to the LDAP/AD server. But how do we know if there are more pages to follow and how do we specify with which control-value we have to send our next query?

This is where we're getting stuck... The server responds with a result set that includes the required paging information but PHP lacks a method to retrieve exactly this information from the result set. PHP provides a wrapper for the LDAP API function [`ldap_parse_result()`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-parse-result.php) but the required last parameter `serverctrlsp` is not exposed to the PHP function, so there is no way to retrieve the required information. A [bug report](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34492) has been filed for this issue but there has been no response since 2005. If the `ldap_parse_result()` function provided the required parameter, using paged results would work like

```
$l = ldap_connect('somehost.mydomain.com');
$pageSize    = 100;
$pageControl = array(
    'oid'        => '1.2.840.113556.1.4.319',
    'iscritical' => true,
    'value'      => sprintf ("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c", 48, 5, 2, 1, $pageSize, 4, 0)

);
$controls = array($pageControl);

ldap_set_option($l, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_bind($l, 'CN=bind-user,OU=my-users,DC=mydomain,DC=com', 'bind-user-password');

$continue = true;
while ($continue) {
    ldap_set_option($l, LDAP_OPT_SERVER_CONTROLS, $controls);
    $sr = ldap_search($l, 'OU=some-ou,DC=mydomain,DC=com', 'cn=*', array('sAMAccountName'), null, null, null, null);
    ldap_parse_result ($l, $sr, $errcode, $matcheddn, $errmsg, $referrals, $serverctrls); // (*)
    if (isset($serverctrls)) {
        foreach ($serverctrls as $i) {
            if ($i["oid"] == '1.2.840.113556.1.4.319') {
                    $i["value"]{8}   = chr($pageSize);
                    $i["iscritical"] = true;
                    $controls        = array($i);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    $info = ldap_get_entries($l, $sr);
    if ($info["count"] < $pageSize) {
        $continue = false;
    }

    for ($entry = ldap_first_entry($l, $sr); $entry != false; $entry = ldap_next_entry($l, $entry)) {
        $dn = ldap_get_dn($l, $entry);
    }
}
```

As you see there is a single line of code `(*)` that renders the whole thing useless. On my way though the sparse information on this subject I found a patch against the PHP 4.3.10 `ext/ldap` by Iñaki Arenaza but neither did I try it nor do I know if the patch can be applied on a PHP5 `ext/ldap`. The patch extends `ldap_parse_result()` to expose the 7th parameter to PHP:

```
--- ldap.c 2004-06-01 23:05:33.000000000 +0200
+++ /usr/src/php4/php4-4.3.10/ext/ldap/ldap.c 2005-09-03 17:02:03.000000000 +0200
@@ -74,7 +74,7 @@
 ZEND_DECLARE_MODULE_GLOBALS(ldap)
 
 static unsigned char third_argument_force_ref[] = { 3, BYREF_NONE, BYREF_NONE, BYREF_FORCE };
-static unsigned char arg3to6of6_force_ref[] = { 6, BYREF_NONE, BYREF_NONE, BYREF_FORCE, BYREF_FORCE, BYREF_FORCE, BYREF_FORCE };
+static unsigned char arg3to7of7_force_ref[] = { 7, BYREF_NONE, BYREF_NONE, BYREF_FORCE, BYREF_FORCE, BYREF_FORCE, BYREF_FORCE, BYREF_FORCE };
 
 static int le_link, le_result, le_result_entry, le_ber_entry;
 
@@ -124,7 +124,7 @@
 #if ( LDAP_API_VERSION > 2000 ) || HAVE_NSLDAP
  PHP_FE(ldap_get_option,   third_argument_force_ref)
  PHP_FE(ldap_set_option,        NULL)
- PHP_FE(ldap_parse_result,   arg3to6of6_force_ref)
+ PHP_FE(ldap_parse_result,   arg3to7of7_force_ref)
  PHP_FE(ldap_first_reference,      NULL)
  PHP_FE(ldap_next_reference,       NULL)
 #ifdef HAVE_LDAP_PARSE_REFERENCE
@@ -1775,14 +1775,15 @@
    Extract information from result */
 PHP_FUNCTION(ldap_parse_result) 
 {
- pval **link, **result, **errcode, **matcheddn, **errmsg, **referrals;
+ pval **link, **result, **errcode, **matcheddn, **errmsg, **referrals, **serverctrls;
  ldap_linkdata *ld;
  LDAPMessage *ldap_result;
+ LDAPControl **lserverctrls, **ctrlp, *ctrl;
  char **lreferrals, **refp;
  char *lmatcheddn, *lerrmsg;
  int rc, lerrcode, myargcount = ZEND_NUM_ARGS();
   
- if (myargcount  6 || zend_get_parameters_ex(myargcount, &link, &result, &errcode, &matcheddn, &errmsg, &referrals) == FAILURE) {
+ if (myargcount  7 || zend_get_parameters_ex(myargcount, &link, &result, &errcode, &matcheddn, &errmsg, &referrals, &serverctrls) == FAILURE) {
   WRONG_PARAM_COUNT;
  }
 
@@ -1793,7 +1794,7 @@
     myargcount > 3 ? &lmatcheddn : NULL,
     myargcount > 4 ? &lerrmsg : NULL,
     myargcount > 5 ? &lreferrals : NULL,
-    NULL /* &serverctrls */,
+    myargcount > 6 ? &lserverctrls : NULL,
     0 );
  if (rc != LDAP_SUCCESS ) {
   php_error(E_WARNING, "%s(): Unable to parse result: %s", get_active_function_name(TSRMLS_C), ldap_err2string(rc));
@@ -1805,6 +1806,29 @@
 
  /* Reverse -> fall through */
  switch(myargcount) {
+  case 7 :
+   zval_dtor(*serverctrls);
+
+   if (lserverctrls != NULL) {
+    array_init(*serverctrls);
+    ctrlp = lserverctrls;
+
+    while (*ctrlp != NULL) {
+     zval *ctrl_array;
+
+     ctrl = *ctrlp;
+     MAKE_STD_ZVAL(ctrl_array);
+     array_init(ctrl_array);
+
+     add_assoc_string(ctrl_array, "oid", ctrl->ldctl_oid,1);
+     add_assoc_bool(ctrl_array, "iscritical", ctrl->ldctl_iscritical);
+     add_assoc_stringl(ctrl_array, "value", ctrl->ldctl_value.bv_val,
+           ctrl->ldctl_value.bv_len,1);
+     add_next_index_zval (*serverctrls, ctrl_array);
+     ctrlp++;
+    }
+    ldap_controls_free (lserverctrls);
+   }
   case 6 :
    zval_dtor(*referrals);
    if (array_init(*referrals) == FAILURE) {
```

Actually the only option left would be to change the Active Directory configuration and raise the maximum result limit. The relevant option is called `MaxPageSize` and can be altered by using `ntdsutil.exe` - please see ["How to view and set LDAP policy in Active Directory by using Ntdsutil.exe"](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;315071&x=12&y=16).

**EDIT** (reference to COM):

Or you can go the other way round and use the COM-approach via ADODB as suggested in the [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php#73636) provided by [eykanal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473075/enumerate-all-users-in-ldap-with-php/1473747#1473747).

Comment: What is the status of this now that PHP 5.4 supports paged LDAP results?

Comment: @Squazic: See answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10140166/11354 down below. Seems to be doable starting with PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 6):

Support for paged results was added in PHP 5.4.

See [ldap_control_paged_result](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-control-paged-result.php) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a full answer, but [this guy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php#73636) was able to do it. I don't understand what he did, though.

By the way, a partial answer is that you CAN get "pages" of results. From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php):

> ```
> resource ldap_search ( resource $link_identifier , string $base_dn ,
>      string $filter [, array $attributes [, int $attrsonly [, int $sizelimit [, 
>      int $timelimit [, int $deref ]]]]] )
> ...
> ```
>
> **sizelimit**   Enables you to limit the count of entries fetched. Setting this to 0 means no limit.
>
> Note: This parameter can NOT override server-side preset sizelimit.
> You can set it lower though.  Some directory server hosts will be
> configured to return no more than a preset number of entries. If this
> occurs, the server will indicate that it has only returned a partial
> results set. This also occurs if you use this parameter to limit the
> count of fetched entries.

I don't know how to specify that you want to search STARTING from a certain position, though. I.e., after you get your first 1000, I don't know how to specify that now you need the next 1000. Hopefully someone else can help you there :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative (which works pre PHP 5.4). If you have 10,000 records you need to get but your AD server only returns 5,000 per page:

```
$ldapSearch = ldap_search($ldapResource, $basedn, $filter, array('member;range=0-4999')); 
$ldapResults = ldap_get_entries($dn, $ldapSearch);
$members = $ldapResults[0]['member;range=0-4999'];

$ldapSearch = ldap_search($ldapResource, $basedn, $filter, array('member;range=5000-10000')); 
$ldapResults = ldap_get_entries($dn, $ldapSearch);
$members = array_merge($members, $ldapResults[0]['member;range=5000-*']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the size limitation using [ldap_control_paged_result](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-control-paged-result.php)

ldap_control_paged_result is used to Enable LDAP pagination by sending the pagination control. The below function worked perfectly in my case.

```
function retrieves_users($conn)
    {
        $dn        = 'ou=,dc=,dc=';
        $filter    = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(sn=*))";
        $justthese = array();

        // enable pagination with a page size of 100.
        $pageSize = 100;

        $cookie = '';

        do {
            ldap_control_paged_result($conn, $pageSize, true, $cookie);

            $result  = ldap_search($conn, $dn, $filter, $justthese);
            $entries = ldap_get_entries($conn, $result);

            if(!empty($entries)){
                for ($i = 0; $i < $entries["count"]; $i++) {
                    $data['usersLdap'][] = array(
                            'name' => $entries[$i]["cn"][0],
                            'username' => $entries[$i]["userprincipalname"][0]
                    );
                }
            }
            ldap_control_paged_result_response($conn, $result, $cookie);

        } while($cookie !== null && $cookie != '');

        return $data;
    }
```